# Parameterized routing on /

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing

I have two types of category: MasterCategory and Category.

1. User can search any master category by the URL and he will get the detail of that MasterCategory:

   `www.xyzabc.com/nameOfMasterCategory`
2. In the detail page of the Master Category there will be mulitple categories which are associated with the Master Category. When user clicks on any one of them the url should become like:

   `www.xyzabc.com/nameOfMasterCategory/nameOfCategory`

I know it can be done by giving a category path in the routing using child routing.
For example

`www.xyzabc.com/category/nameOfMasterCategory/nameOfCategory`

But I want it to work on / without prefixing any hardcoded category
For example:

```
www.xyzabc.com/category/nameOfMasterCategory/nameOfCategory
```

Example:

```
https://www.sulekha.com/austria-education-consultants/kota
```

How to create routing for this?

Comment: OK. But what is your question?

Comment: How to create routing for this?

Comment: The same way you would do it with the `'category'` prefix, but... without the prefix. Have you *tried* anything?

Comment: I tried with prefixing category. It is working fine. But without the prefix, it doesn't allow me to put the paramterized routing on /.

Comment: Then post your two attempts. Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':masterCategory',
        component: MasterCategoryComponent
     },
     {
        path: ':masterCategory/:childCategory',
        component: ChildCategoryComponent
     }
]
```

Or use nested route

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':masterCategory',
        component: MasterCategoryComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':childCategory',
                component: ChildCategoryComponent
             }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed. but I have question, if suppose there is a component which has a path similar to the masterCategory. then how can we handle that in routing?.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the new route does **not** have a parameter like `':something'` and just has a static value for `path` like this `path: 'static-path'` then you can add that new route to the **beginning** of your route configuration because `path: 'static-path'` will match `path: ':masterCategory'`, so if it is not the first route, then `path: ':masterCategory'` will always be picked, otherwise you just need to subscribe to the parameter change observable in your `MasterComponent` and do you checks there to see if it's a master category or some other path, I am not sure if my point has been made clear

Comment: Yes.. u made your point clear. I will put the static routes before the dynamic route.

Comment: If the answer helped solve your problem, please consider accepting it

Comment: I have. It is not reflecting publicly.